# How can I use Google Analytics code in React JS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I want to use below Google Analytics code in my react JS app in the script tag.

When I put the below code in Helmet I showing a syntax error?

How Can I use it?

```html
<script>
  (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
      "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(),
      event: "gtm.js",
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j = d.createElement(s),
      dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
    j.async = true;
    j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "GTM-Code");
</script>
<!--  End Google Tag Manager  -->
<!-- Makes it possible to add onclick attribute to buttons and such -->
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
      var anchor = anchors[i];
      anchor.onclick = function () {
        code = this.getAttribute("whenClicked");
        eval(code);
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do below two steps, Copy the code below and paste it onto every page of your test environment.
Paste this code as high in the **head** of the page as possible:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl; 
f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Additionally, paste this code immediately after the opening **body** tag:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

As per the provided source code, you didn't add noscript tag after the body tag.

> Please provide exact error you are having to get more understanding of
> the issue.

Comment: any way to use react-helmet?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a 3rd party library such as [React GA](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) that handles script injection for you.